# Does the Max processes in /proc/<pid>/limits signifies the maximum number of child processes for that process

Tags: linux, process

What does the Max processes in /proc//limits signifies?

Does it signifies maximum number of child processes for that process??

How to limit number of child processes for a particular process at runtime in linux?

```
cat /proc/<pid>/limits

Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             29397                29397                processes 
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       29397                29397                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Answer (score 0):

That number is exactly what you would get by doing `getrlimit` on `RLIMIT_NPROC`. That is described in the manual page:

> The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads)
>   **that can be created for the real user ID of the calling process**. 
>   Upon encountering this limit, fork(2) fails with the error EAGAIN.

So every time you fork the system checks all your processes before allowing this one process to `fork`. If you lower the limit for some process - perhaps with `ulimit` for the shell or with `setrlimit` - the system still counts all your processes but it checks the number against the new limit.

Comment: So How to limit number of child processes for a particular process at runtime in linux?

Comment: @Raghu I don't think there's any easy and meaningful way to do this. There was a patch adding a cgroup fork limit but I don't think it got included in the mainline.

Comment: I think you can actually limit the number of processes in a cgroup and that will enforce a limit for a certain process. https://lwn.net/Articles/461462/

Comment: I am working on sandboxing, As a part of it i need to detect fork bomb. For that one suggestion is about limiting number of processes that the main process will create. Is there any other option to detect fork bomb?

Comment: @Raghu Could be but I don't know of any other. cgroups are generally the way to isolate things in linux.